# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zerog.lax.LAX

Tags: java, cplex

I'm trying to install a software called CPLEX, from IBM. They provided me with an .bin installer. When I try to run it, I get an error when a class is not found. Since I'm not familiar with this language, I'm not sure what to do and how to fix it. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and when I run java --version, I get this:

```
openjdk 11.0.20.1 2023-08-24
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.20.1+1-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.20.1+1-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Error I'm getting:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-30-0-248:~$ ./cos_installer-12.10.0.0.R0-CC439ML-linux-x86-64.bin
Preparing to install
Extracting the JRE from the installer archive...
Unpacking the JRE...
Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive...
Configuring the installer for this system's environment...

Launching installer...

Error: Could not find or load main class com.zerog.lax.LAX
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zerog.lax.LAX
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu2204 and CPLEX 12.10. I solved it by updating the CPLEX version to the current one (22.1)

Answer (score 0):

This "feels" like a version incompatibility.

**Your CPLEX 12.10.0 is heavily outdated: it's from 2019.**

This version you are trying to install officially only supports Ubuntu <= 18 LTS which means you are not only using an future LTS version (20 LTS; slow iteration) but even one more future LTS version (22 LTS).

Your error is related to the installer-tool (Java-based) and while one would expect some backwards-compatibility, especially with Java 11 (LTS), there might be some issue with your Java 11 Version you provide and what's expected. But this is only a guess.

#### Workarounds

##### A:

I highly highly recommend to get a newer CPLEX version. Depending on your usage, you might see other issues too (e.g. no python > 3.7 support) too.

##### B:

If thats not possible, which would be not good, consider downgrading your linux distribution (again: not the greatest of all ideas).

##### C:

The last recommendation: Contact their support although i expect them to tell you too, that your OS distribution is not supported.